# POST fails with Retrofit (connect timed out) but works with Postman

Tags: android, json, post, kotlin, retrofit

*SOLVED: stupid mistake, I had https://foo.foo.com:433 instead of https://foo.foo.com:443...*

I've implemented Retrofit and I'm trying to send a POST request with JSON data as JsonObject. It's not working and I get a failure "connect time out", but I can send a POST request without problem via Postman. At first I thought it was because of the header, I've tried with an Interceptor and to use @Header instead of @Headers. Thank you for your help.

**Postman**

[image: Postman header]
[image: Postman body]

**Log from HttpLoggingInterceptor()**

```
Jun 30, 2018 10:22:09 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST https://foo.foo.com:433/
Jun 30, 2018 10:22:09 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Content-Type: application/json
Jun 30, 2018 10:22:09 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Content-Length: 132
Jun 30, 2018 10:22:09 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: 
Jun 30, 2018 10:22:09 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: {"transport":"web","userId":"ggrojeomieje2","moduleId":105,"moduleName":"signal","moduleVersion":1,"operation":"signal","params":{}}
Jun 30, 2018 10:22:09 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> END POST (132-byte body)
Jun 30, 2018 10:22:19 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
failure connect timed out [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@3850debc
INFO: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

**Api Interface**

```
interface ApiEndpoints {
    @POST("/")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    fun sendRequest(@Body json: PostModel): Call<ResponseModel>
}
```

**Retrofit Client**

```
class ApiClient {
    val service = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://foo.foo.com:433")
        .client(client) // Implement HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiEndpoints::class.java)
}
```

**Api Call**

```
val test = ApiClient().service.sendRequest(
            PostModel("web",
                    "ggrojeomieje2",
                    105,
                    "signal",
                    1,
                    "signal",
                    Params())
)

test.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseModel> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseModel>?, response: Response<ResponseModel>?) {
            println("response " + response?.body()?.params?.timestamp.toString())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseModel>?, t: Throwable?) {
            println("failure " + t?.message.toString())
        }
    })
```

**Models**

```
data class ResponseModel(val params: Params?)


data class PostModel(var transport: String? = null,
                     var userId: String? = null,
                     var moduleId: Int? = 0,
                     var moduleName: String? = null,
                     var moduleVersion: Int? = 0,
                     var operation: String? = null,
                     var params: Params?
)

data class Params(var timestamp: Unit? = null)
```

**Response**

```
{"params":{"timestamp":1.530346984546E9}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set time out value in `OkHttpClient`.

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
```

Also try changing request body types like `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `form-data` and header like this `@Headers({"content-type: application/json"})`

or

Check is there any network related issue or just try some simple `GET` method too failing.

Comment: Just tried, now I get this error in onFailure(): `Failed to connect to foo.foo.com/54.246.216.106:433`. Thanks

Comment: Check is there any network related issue or just try some simple GET method too failing.

Comment: Stupid mistake, I had `https://foo.foo.com:433` instead of `https://foo.foo.com:443`... Thank you for your time

Comment: Oh, I too didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, I had https://foo.foo.com:433 instead of https://foo.foo.com:443...